# How do you divide a big array without separation into groups of three?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem, how can I divide a large array without separation into groups of 3 ? (To get three colors => Red, Green, Blue for each pixel, in fact, I just want to convert 1D array into 2D array with groups of 3).

The array I want to divide is like this (The array is really big, it's about 130,000 long, and I try to find a quick way to do what I want):

[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 96, 0, 96, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26, 28, 28, 32, 36, 46, 39, 32, 34, 44, 35, 28, 28, 40, 55, 41, 44, 48, 49, 52, 52, 52, 31, 39, 57, 61, 56, 50, 60, 46, 51, 52, 50, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 9, 9, 9, 12, 11, 12, …]

I made it with python but my computer crashed (yes really :D) I can't find how to do with Javascript and I hope that my computer will not crash anymore :/, can someone help me ?

My Python code (As my computer crashed, I don't know if that's work):

```
def cut(array, cutsize):
    for i in range(0, len(array), cutsize):
        yield array[cutsize:i+cutsize]

print(list(cut(lineList, 3)))
```

**Thanks you for your help**.

Comment: What have you tried and what is the issue with your solution?

Comment: Ah! I don't try anything yet because I don't see how I can do that at all :/ And I don't understand why the array is like this !

Comment: What do you mean "like this"?

Comment: It's not an array with (for example: red:125; blue:12, green: 52 ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Buffer** array looks like the data (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas - Uint8ClampedArray) of an **ImageData** object.

You could get any pixel's RGBa color by using the code below:

```
const xCoord = 50;
const yCoord = 100;
const canvasWidth = 1024;

const getColorIndicesForCoord = (x, y, width) => {
  const red = y * (width * 4) + x * 4;
  return [red, red + 1, red + 2, red + 3];
};

const colorIndices = getColorIndicesForCoord(xCoord, yCoord, canvasWidth);

const [redIndex, greenIndex, blueIndex, alphaIndex] = colorIndices;
```

Of course for this code to work, you need to know the width of the image in pixels.

The main point is that every four numbers in your **array** codes an RGBa color:

```
// first pixel's color:
const red1 = array[0]
const green1 = array[1]
const blue1 = array[2]
const alpha1 = array[3]

// second pixel's color:
const red2 = array[4]
const green2 = array[5]
const blue2 = array[6]
const alpha2 = array[7]

// and so on...
```

But my concern is that the length of your Buffer is not divisible by four, so you may need to convert it first:

```
function processimage(e) {
 var buffer = e.target.result;
 var bitmap = getBMP(buffer); 
 var imageData = convertToImageData(bitmap);
 ctx1.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); // ctx1 can be found on the link below
}
```

More on Bitmap to canvas imageData: https://www.i-programmer.info/projects/36-web/6234-reading-a-bmp-file-in-javascript.html?start=2

Comment: Thanks for your help, I succeeded !

Comment: I’m happy that I could help :)